# What's best pass data to another activity or do two queries to sqlite

Tags: android

I've a big questionaire to fill, so I've decide to split it in two activities/screens. My question is:
- Should I send the data from activity1 to activity2 (startActivityForResult) and insert all the data on sqlite with an insert on activity2?
- Should I make an insert on activity1 and an update on activity2 since I know the row _id?

The option 1 is better to ensure the user fills all the questionaire, right?

Comment: Why do you have to update it in activity2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First option is better, because with this you will never have incomplete information in database (what happens if user exits from app when he finishes with first screen?) and you only will make a unique call to insert data.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already considered:

1. Using shared preferences in activity 1, read it from activity 2, then insert; or,
2. Using a static array or map, which both activities can access?

I don't know what your security needs are but either two options seem so much simpler, especially number 2.